# Making program exclusively executable from another program

Tags: c#

I want to create a launch program for a separate exe. I need the primary program (not the launch) to be inaccessible outside of the launcher.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? it will help us help you.

Answer (score 4):

It is fundamentally impossible to do this securely.  Anything that the launcher can do, the user can also do.

You can make it harder for the user by making the launcher pass a cryptographically signed timestamp to the separate program.  However, the user could extract the private key from the launcher and sign a timestamp by hand.

You could make the program check its parent PID and make sure that the launcher EXE is signed with your own private key, but the user could modify the program to remove that check.

You can also turn the EXE into a DLL, with a method called by the launcher, but the user could write his own EXE that also calls that method.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to require an argument when running the second program, although this is easily exploitable. You don't say really what this is for, so it might be good enough.

Depending on what your launcher program does, you might be able to check if those operations have been done, and if not, exit the program.

If you need this to be particularly secure, you might be able to set up some private-public key system, and encrypt a dynamic piece of info (like the timestamp). Honestly, I think this would be more work than it's worth, and it would still be exploitable if either of the programs for disassembled.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to implement the main functionality as a separate *DLL* file and invoke it from a launching application. 
This is way the main features aren't exactly a separate application, so it may be not exactly what you want, but it's separated and require another application (a launcher) to be run.

Answer (score 0):

An appropriate solution depends on exactly what you are trying to prevent.

If your goal is that "under no circumstances shall a skilled hacker ever launch B.exe except through A.exe", that is difficult to achieve.

If your goal is "I don't want the user to accidentally launch B.exe because A.exe is what they should be using", there are options.  For example, pass a command line parameter from A.exe to B.exe that an average user would not know to pass in.

Answer (score 0):

I have two proposals to achieve what you want.

1. Does the second exe need to actually be an exe? Can you make it a library call instead? Invoke the functionality as a thread running under your launchers process.
2. Use unpublished command line arguments. If they are not supplied have the 2nd exe terminate. This is not completely secure, but I believe this is how modern game launchers work.

ultimately, I do not think there is a way to do this without 'security through obscurity'

Answer (score 0):

You could create a mutex with a Guid as name in the launcher. Then check the mutex in the program. Like others have said, this is not very secure but will prevent most people from launching the program directly.